# Postfix → Dovecot LMTP: User does not exist: uid@domain

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I am trying to have Postfix deliver local mails via Dovecot's LMTP (among other things to replace procmail with sieve). Up to now, I've been using `mailbox_command = procmail - a "$EXTENSION"`, delivering to local `~/Maildir`s.

Following http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixDovecotLMTP, I configured (postfix is chrooted) in `/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf`

```
service lmtp {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
    group=postfix
    user=postfix
    mode=0600
  }
```

and added to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

Now, that almost works (Postfix talks to the LMTP socket), but LMTP is confused about the "user" `eudoxos@mydomain.eu` containg the domain:

```
Jan 11 08:22:17 s18015955 postfix/lmtp[7374]: 3D84E19B0290E: to=<eudoxos@mydomain.eu>, orig_to=<fristname.lastname@mydomain.eu>, relay=iota.mydomain.eu[private/dovecot-lmtp], delay=0.01, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host iota.mydomain.eu[private/dovecot-lmtp] said: 550 5.1.1 <eudoxos@mydomain.eu> User doesn't exist: eudoxos@mydomain.eu (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

LMTP should be looking just for `eudoxos` (in LDAP) instead of `eudoxos@mydomain.eu`. How can I achieve that?

If I were using delivery program (LDA), recipient username is specified as argument (like `mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -f "$SENDER" -a "$RECIPIENT"`), but I had issues with log permissions using LDA (Dovecot wiki discourages using LDA for that reason).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to set

```
user_filter = (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=%n)
```

in `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext`.

Answer (score 20):

You need to set:

```
auth_username_format = %Ln
```

In ***conf.d/10-auth.conf***

That removes the domain name, and the '@'.

Comment: This fixed my problem when not using LDAP. 